# Calculating width along grid points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry

I have a shapefile of a glacier for which I need to determine the width along every point of the flow line (the brown dots).

I want to do this by determing the length of a perpendicular line through each of the brown grid points within the glacier's boundaries

How can I do this efficiently?

[image].

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the transect tool from here: http://gis4geomorphology.com/stream-transects-partial/
2. Use 'Minimum Bounding Geometry' tool, or some other method to create a polygon from your points
3. Clip the lines with the polygon
4. Calculate line lengths

[image: Minimum Bounding Geometry Tool Settings]
[image: Minimum Bounding Geometry Output (Convex Hull)]